# How to insert strings and variables into print statements?

Tags: python

I am trying to program something that will display the variable that I wrote earlier in a print statement but whenever I run the code it doesn't display the variable, it just says "None".

My code:

```
sidewalkclosed = True
raining = True
xPos = 400
yPos = 400
print("Your robot is located at",print(yPos),"on the y axis and",print(xPos),"on the x 
axis.")
```

Comment: ```print(f"Your robot is located at {yPos} on the y axis and {xPos} on the x 
axis.")```

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```py
sidewalkclosed = True
raining = True
xPos = 400
yPos = 400
print("Your robot is located at",yPos,"on the y axis and",xPos,"on the x 
axis.")
#### or ####
print(f"Your robot is located at {yPos} on the y axis and {xPos} on the x 
axis.")
# More Ways
#### or ####
print("Your robot is located at {} on the y axis and {} on the x axis.".format(yPos,xPos))

#### or ####
print("Your robot is located at %d on the y axis and %d on the x axis." % (yPos,xPos))
# Here %d (Or %i) for integer and for string type you can use %s.
# And for float you can use (%f,%e,%g) and more.
```

#### ERROR

Here you got None Instead of 400 and 400 this is because the print function returns None.

---

#### Execution Of Your Code.

```py
print("Your robot is located at",print(yPos),"on the y axis and",print(xPos),"on the x 
axis.")
```

##### OUTPUT From Your Code

```
400
400
Your robot is located at None on the y axis and None on the x axis.
```

In this code when the print function read the input he got
`print(yPos)` and `print(xPos)` He runs those two print functions and
capture the returning value Which is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using f strings -

```
print(f"Your robot is located at {yPos} on the y axis and {xPos} on the x axis")
```

Answer (score 1):

you have put print() inside print() for some reason just change it to

```
print("Your robot is located at",yPos,"on the y axis and",xPos,"on the x axis.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sidewalkclosed = True
raining = True
xPos = 400
yPos = 400
print(f"Your robot is located at {yPos} on the y axis and {xPos} on the x axis.")
```